# I am struggling making a basic image slider with jquery cycle 2

Tags: html, jquery

I have been taking online courses at Udemy and have been struggling with a image slider lesson. I have followed all the steps to make a basic slider. The lesson had me make my banner to have overflow:hidden and then had me go to jquery cycle 2 in order to copy the script links and I did. Then I put my class as "banner cycle-slideshow" just as the lesson instructed me. However it did not make my image slider function. It only stays on the first image. Any help? Here are my codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/owner/Desktop/HTML/css/style6.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<header>
 <div class=left>
  <a href="/Users/owner/Desktop/HTML/pages/page-6.html">
    <img src="" height="100" width="200" alt="logo"></a>
   </div>
       <div class="right">
       <form> 
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
       <input type="submit" value=">">
       </form>
       </div>
       <div>
           
       </div>
       <nav class="main-menu">
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Ways to help</a>
                   <ul class="drop">
                       <li><a href="https://homeguides.sfgate.com/ecofriendly-mean- 
    78718.html" target="_blank">Option 1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="https://www.wheelsforwishes.org/news/live-a-more- 
    eco-friendly-lifestyle/" target="_blank">Option 2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="https://money.usnews.com/money/blogs/my- 
    money/slideshows/ways-to-live-green-on-a-budget" target="_blank">Option 3</a> 
   </li>
                </ul>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">Tell a friend!</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
       </nav>
   </header>
  <section class="banner cycle-slideshow">
   <img src="" alt="Banner 1"> 
   <img src=""  alt="Banner 2">
  </section>
    <section>
       <article>
        <main class="push">
            <h1 style="color: green;">GO GREEN</h1>
            <p>Save the planet by going green. Be eco friendly! 
            Eco-friendly items and materials are defined as being 
            not environmentally harmful. These products promote green 
            living or green manufacturing methods that lessen the amount 
            or types of resources used. In short, eco-friendly products 
            help the earth, not cause it harm.</p>
        </main>
       </article>
    </section>
    

    <aside class=beta>
        <div>
            <h3>Widget</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">2019</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2020</li>
                 <li><a href="#">2021</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </aside>
     <hr>

     <footer>
    <div class="easy">
        <h3>Footer Menu</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="easy">
        <h3>Footer Menu</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="easy">
        <h3>Footer Menu</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="final">
        <address>
            Written by <a href="mailto:raymondhernandez_4@msn.com">Raymond 
Hernandez</a><br>
            Visit us at:<br>
            <a href="#".com>#.com</a><br>
            100, Someplace, Somewhere far. 3495<br>
            USA
        </address>
    </div>
    </footer>
    <div class="final">
        <p><small>Copyright &copy; 2021. All rights reserved.</small></p>
    </div>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CDN URL you're linking for Cycle2 is wrong.

The file you're linking to is a deleted file, so you can get it from Cloudfare instead:

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!